# Standalone Jetty - configure multiple context paths for same context instance

Tags: java, deployment, jetty

Is it possible to configure jetty - vers. 9 (server config files or context xml files) so that the same context instance has the multiple context paths? (that point to the same loaded application, not different instances of the same .war).

In the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html) it seams that only one context path can be set.

I need this because I want to set the default context path (root /) of my webapps without changing the context .xml files of my applications (and switch the / path from one app to another without restarting them) and also, to have them mapped to logical context paths that I can use internally (different purposes) without changing the links.

Thank you.

Comment: This is rather complicated to follow.  Can you edit your question to show what you have, what you have tried, what sort of errors or issues you have encountered or are stuggling with, and what end result you want to accomplish.   Use lists, or tables, or ascii art, or diagrams, or pictures if you must.