# Multiple context paths in one jetty-web.xml for JAX-RS application running on a Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, war, contextpath

I have seen versions of this question asked and even one version from [multiple years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732783/standalone-jetty-configure-multiple-context-paths-for-same-context-instance) that is exactly what I'm asking, but alas, there was no answer to that one. So here it goes: I have a tomcat based web application that can take many different forms based on the settings of a few embedded JSON files. What I'm trying to accomplish is using the URL as the basis to inform the application which version to use instead of making multiple instances of the application for each different configuration.

Current:

`http://<server>/Version1`,`http://<server>/Version2`,`http://<server>/Version3`

***same application, three WAR files, just renamed from each other / one server context path each***

Preferred:

`http://<server>/Version1`,`http://<server>/Version2`,`http://<server>/Version3`

***one application / one WAR file / three server context paths***

Is this possible? If so, how is it accomplished? If not, does anyone have a clever idea?

Note: Neither Maven nor Gradle are in use.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you want multiple context paths?

Even if you have 1 war, and 3 context paths, that war will be loaded 3 times and each one will be isolated from each other (classloader, object instances, sessions, cookies, resources, etc)

You could, on the other hand, do some custom URI manipulation before a single webapp.

Here's an example of a single WebApp (war) loaded on the root context (`/`), only one time, and then a HandlerWrapper (a Jetty concept) that does the URI version identification and URI manipulation, with a request attribute used to communicate the version back to the webapp and it's servlets.

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.IO;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

/**
 * This is a single Webapp on root, and a Handler that identifies a URI pattern
 * and informs the webapp what version to use.
 */
public class UriIdentifiedBehaviorDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        WebAppContext webapp = createWebApp();
        webapp.setContextPath("/"); // root

        UriVersionHandler uriVersionHandler = new UriVersionHandler();
        uriVersionHandler.setHandler(webapp);

        server.setHandler(uriVersionHandler);
        server.start();

        try
        {
            // direct access
            demoCall(server.getURI().resolve("/demo/"));
            // attempt at version, but missing number
            demoCall(server.getURI().resolve("/version/demo/"));
            // versioned
            demoCall(server.getURI().resolve("/version1/demo/"));
            demoCall(server.getURI().resolve("/version99/demo/"));
        }
        finally
        {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void demoCall(URI destUri) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)destUri.toURL().openConnection();
        int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
        System.out.printf("GET [%s] resulted in Response Status Code [%d]%n", 
            destUri, statusCode);

        if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        try (InputStream in = http.getInputStream())
        {
            String responseBody = IO.toString(in, UTF_8);
            System.out.printf("Response Body: %s%n", responseBody);
        }
    }

    private static WebAppContext createWebApp()
    {
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        Path warPath = Paths.get("src/main/wars/webapp-a.war");
        webapp.setBaseResource(new PathResource(warPath));

        webapp.addServlet(DemoServlet.class, "/demo/*");

        return webapp;
    }

    public static class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.printf("Version (header) is [%s]%n", 
                req.getAttribute("my.uri.version"));
        }
    }

    public static class UriVersionHandler extends HandlerWrapper
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(String target, 
                           Request baseRequest, 
                           HttpServletRequest request, 
                           HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            String actualTarget = target;
            String requestPath = baseRequest.getHttpURI().getPath();
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^\\/version([0-9]+)\\/");
            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(requestPath);
            if (mat.find())
            {
                // we are in a version identified syntax!
                String version = mat.group(1);
                request.setAttribute("my.uri.version", version);
                actualTarget = requestPath.substring(mat.end(1));
            }

            getHandler().handle(actualTarget, baseRequest, request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

which shows the following output ...

```
GET [http://127.0.1.1:8080/demo/] resulted in Response Status Code [200]
Response Body: Version (header) is [null]

GET [http://127.0.1.1:8080/version/demo/] resulted in Response Status Code [404]
GET [http://127.0.1.1:8080/version1/demo/] resulted in Response Status Code [200]
Response Body: Version (header) is [1]

GET [http://127.0.1.1:8080/version99/demo/] resulted in Response Status Code [200]
Response Body: Version (header) is [99]
```

FYI, This kind of speculative question is best on the [jetty-users mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/jetty-users), or as an issue on the [Eclipse Jetty Issue tracker](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues) (as a question).

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. Apologies for not being explicit enough but what you are showing here is an embedded server and what I'm running is a Tomcat server, not embedded. Therefore, I cannot wrap a UriHandler around a non-existent Server.

Comment: If you are using `jetty-home` (or the older `jetty-distribution`) you can accomplish this with an inserted custom Handler (via xml) and a normal webapp (war) deployment.

Comment: There is no jetty-home. This is a tomcat server running many different WAR files, mine just being one of them.

Comment: I don't understand, you have `jetty-web.xml` in your title, and `jetty` in your tag.  These mentions of tomcat are confusing.   Also yes, you can still have a custom handler for some (not all) webapps on a multi-webapp Jetty standalone server (not embedded).

Comment: I should have stated 'Java API for RESTful Web Services'  (JAX-RS), which utilizes a jetty-web.xml file. It is NOT a true jetty based application and is only using a jetty standalone server for debugging purposes but not in deployment.